# Using Python to send commands to a subshell

Tags: python, shell, subshell

I need to send commands to shell "MYSHELL>" after it has been initiated.

```
prcs = subprocess.Popen("MYSHELL; cmnd1; cmnd2;",shell=True,
subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

outputPrcs, err =  prcs.communicate()
print outputPrcs
```

Problem only entering shell is implemented, Other commands (cmnd1; cmnd2;)aren't sent.

Result:
MYSHELL>

Comment: Probably because `MYSHELL` is still executing. What your command means is "Start MYSHELL, wait for it to finish, and then do cmnd1 and cmnd2"

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to send "cmnd1" and "cmnd2" to your shell as input, or do you want to execute other programs?

Comment: I want to send cmnd1 cmnd2 to MYSHELL as input in that shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
communicate(self, input=None)
   Interact with process: Send data to stdin.  Read data from
   stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.  Wait for
   process to terminate.  The optional input argument should be a
   string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data
   should be sent to the child.
```

Notice, `Wait for process to terminate.`  I think what you need is [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/).  It isn't in the standard library, but it'll do what you want.

Example:

```
import pexpect

process = pexpect.spawn("python")
process.expect_exact(">>> ")
process.sendline('print("It works")')
process.expect("\n.*\n")
response = process.after.strip()
print(response)
```

Output:

```
It works
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send input to your shell then you should pass it as an argument in `communicate`, like so:

```
prcs = subprocess.Popen("MYSHELL",shell=True,
subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

outputPrcs, err =  prcs.communicate("cmnd1; cmnd2;")
print outputPrcs
```

test:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> p = Popen("python", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> o,e = p.communicate("print 'it works'")
>>> print o
it works

>>>
```

Comment: I tried code above, it works. Instead of python.I used bash and a echo it works.
But, still doesn't work with MYSHELL>

Answer (score 0):

It will work @Ahmed. Try below code on linux:

```
from subprocess import *  
cmd = "MYSHELL\ncmd1\ncmd2\n"
p = Popen('/bin/bash', shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)    
o, e = p.communicate(cmd)    

print('Output: ' + o.decode('ascii'))  
print('Error: '  + e.decode('ascii'))  
print('code: ' + str(p.returncode))
```